# Jquery wild card character

Tags: jquery, controls, wildcard

I have 3 controls with id `control_1`, `control_2`, `control_3`.

I want to hide these controls.

Currently I am using this:

```
$('#control_1').hide();
$('#control_2').hide();
$('#control_3').hide();
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Can I do something like `$('control_*').hide();`?

Is there a way to find controls with start with a specific name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For completeness, you can use the [starts with](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) attribute filter:

```
$('[id^="control_"]').hide();
```

That said, for most purposes it would be better to go with one of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Instead, you can set same class to your controls and hide them like that :

```
$('.controlClass').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not replacing IDs with a class like `.controls`? Then just use:

```
$(".controls").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

> $('#control_1,#control_2,#control3').hide();

or use [attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue)