# How to select all images inside any element whose class starts with "pajina" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to select like this

```
var imgs = $('.pajina* img');
```

Then I will do something else with the images variable later on....mas tarde

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389005/jquery-wild-card-character

Comment: it's not a dupe of that question, class names are different than IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var imgs = $('[class*="pajina"] img');
```

Comment: The request is for a 'starts with', not a 'contains'.

Comment: @Flimzy: you seem like an angry person who is not willing to contribute anything.  I feel bad that you are so frustrated with yourself.

Comment: @Shiznitos: I'm not sure why you think I'm an angry person. And I guess trying to provide you with the _correct_ answer to your question doesn't count as contributing? It's no skin off my back if you don't want the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[class*=" pajina"],[class^="pajina"]').find('img')
```

will select any elements starting with "pajina", or any elements with " pajina" in the class name, which happens with multiple class names.

Comment: The request is for a 'starts with', not a 'contains'.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding.  Guess what, `^=` is ___less___ effective in this case.

Comment: No need to get snippy.  In many of cases, ^= _is_ more effective, if multiple classes aren't used. Nonetheless, your answer now looks correct.