# Is there a way to select an element similar to CSS stacking in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`each` function on an `<a>` tag but starting with my `ul`'s ID.

```
$('#ulID.li.a').each(function() {
    //do stuff here.
});
```

Is this even close to how would I do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do, can you clarify?

Comment: like this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389005/jquery-wild-card-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the "."'s like so:

```
    $('#ulID li a').each(function() {
//do stuff here.});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what you're looking for:

```
$('#ulID > li > a').each(function() {
    //do stuff here.
});
```

Or maybe this is sufficient:

```
$('#ulID a').each(function() {
    //do stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use spaces just like you would in CSS.

```
$("#ulID li a").each(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a class name instead of id.  This way you can apply to all.